# How to dynamically load strings.xml easily?

Tags: java, android, string, dynamic, internationalization

I'm working on `android i18n` now. There are some `strings.xml` files in so many `values-xxxx` directories, but the product manager want to put these hole `strings.xml` files into the server, app get `strings.xml` File the rom network by a language-parameter dynamicly.But strings.xml is used in these ways: @string/xx, Widget.setText(R.string.xx), getString(R.string.xx), Toast.make(x, R.string.x, x) and so on... How to dynamic load android strings.xml easily? Or do you got a easier way to solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Resources are read-only, so you can't replace them. use localization features (-en, -it, -de ...)  for language

Comment: product manager ? What ?

Comment: Your product manager shouldn't interfere with the developers work. Really.

Answer (score 1):

Frome one app I worked on:

After starting the app make an api call. The server responds with a JSON, containing all the strings. After parsing it, we can dynamically set all the strings in the right context or keep objects or even the json for getting the strings when required.

Hope this idea can help you.

Answer (score 1):

i do understand that product manager wants to change this for a reason.

My Solution would be as follows:

1. Keep all string related to different language on server with different url pattern. In short url to get string should be like `http://www.example.com/strings/{lang_param}/` example: `http://www.example.com/strings/en/`, `http://www.example.com/strings/pt-br/` something like this.
2. Let  server return JSON, where in key of strings would be same but the values changes based on url parameter i.e `lang_param`. Along with json server must return an identity has to indicate whether some strings items are changed or not. This identity hash  must be kept in shared preference such that next time app boots-up you can query server check hash and if they are different mean some new changes are there get them in.
3. It is mandatory that you keep default strings.xml in internal memory of application using `File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);` given on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html.
4. Once you get the new file update internal memory json file and create a utility method that parses this json. Please note that you need to maintain different hashes and json strings files based on different languages.